# Quering a range of ids in the same order [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select the names of these ids in this SAME order! ids: 1, 2, 3, 20 and 10

Let's say we have this "users" table in a MySQL DBMS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dzgs.jpg

I tried this:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3,20,10);
```

expecting this:
a,b,c,e,d

but ended up with:
a,b,c,d,e

So is there any way of achieving this through SQL? Thanks in advance..

Comment: is it sql server or Mysql or Oracle ??

Answer (score 0):

Do not know what you want to achieve, but in principle you can `order by` equations like

```
SELECT name FROM users ORDER BY
  id = 1 DESC,
  id = 2 DESC,
  id = 3 DESC,
  id = 20 DESC,
  id = 10 DESC;
```

since `(id = 1) = true` for the first row, this is casted to `1` and with `DESC` this will be the first row and all other below which will evaluate to `0`.

For the next row `id=1` will be `0`, but `id=2` will be `1`. Since all other rows evaluate to `0`, this puts the row with id=2 at the second position, ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
  from users
 where id in (1, 2, 3, 20, 10)
 order by case
            when id = 1 then 1
            when id = 2 then 2
            when id = 3 then 3
            when id = 20 then 4
            when id = 10 then 5
            else id
          end
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use the `field()` function:

```
order by field(id, 1, 2, 3, 20, 10)
```